# Find own PDF documents on google

Tags: seo, google-search

I need to find if and how many PDF documents are index by google on one of my websites. So far I had no luck.

Is there any way to "ask" google to show me only PDF documents indexed from my website? Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this search query:

```
site:yoursite.com filetype:pdf
```